# Pass a password as an environment variable through SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, remote-access, sudo

Here is what I know:

`echo "password" | sudo SOME_COMMAND`

The above mentioned command will log in as *root* directly in Bash shell and run `SOME_COMMAND`.

What I am trying to do:

I want to perform same task, but from a remote machine. For that I want to pass the *password as a variable* via an SSH command. Something like this:

`ssh -o PASSWORD=password user@hostA 'echo $PASSWORD | sudo SOME_COMMAND'`

(Reference: *[When ssh'ing, how can I set an environment variable on the server that changes from session to session?](https://superuser.com/questions/163167/when-sshing-how-can-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-server-that-changes-f)*)

But it doesn't pass the `$PASSWORD` variable.

How can I do it?

**Simple summary:**

Here is what I want to do:

I want to pass a variable to remote host when I log in through SSH so I can access it in the remote host script.

Comment: To pass `sudo` password over `stdin`, try adding [`-S` or `--stdin`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/sudo/) option to `sudo`...

Comment: @anishsane How do i pass any env variable to remote shell using ssh?

Comment: `ssh user@host variable=value command` ?? e.g. `ssh user@host PASSWORD=$PASSWORD command`

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work , I tried this 
`ssh -t user@host VAR=123 'echo $VAR'` and `ssh user@host VAR=123 'echo $VAR'` 

It gives blank output

Comment: Comments on the highest voted answer to related question explain that the server configuration must *explicitely* accept the variable. Anyway in a security point of view, what you have written is terrible: you store a password allowing root access in a script. You could have a look on that other post on [Information Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/151871/harden-root-remote-access/151876)

Comment: @mihir6692, that's because `echo` binary receives it as an environment variable. But echo itself does not process environment. So, if you have a shell script, then the variable will be accessible in it. e.g. `ssh user@host var=123 /tmp/abcd`; where abcd contains `echo "var='$var'"`. Alternately, this will work: `ssh user@host var=123 eval 'echo a=\$var'`. Of course, eval based approach has shell injection issues. So proceed with caution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *sshpass* utility to do this task.
But this is not a secure way; your password is not in an encrypted format.

Reference: *[sshpass: Login To SSH Server / Provide SSH Password Using A Shell Script](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/)*

Comment: Nope `sshpass` is not avaiable in my machine and i can't install it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `sudo` and `ssh` in one line. Here is [a discussion and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680694/how-to-pass-password-in-bash-without-prompting-to-ask-to-type-in/42682784#42682784) that I was answering yesterday on Super User.

---

To pass a variable though a *pipe* you can do the following...

```
echo "Hello, World!" | ssh USER@HOST cat
```

Other methods would be passing files via `scp` or `rsync`.

Comment: Can you check summary of my Question? I just want to pass a variable to remote host from my host machine.